Why does self.root.destroy() throw 'Error in bgerror: can't invoke "tk" command: application has been destroyed'?
Background:
Mixing the TkAgg backend (and Tk) in CustomTkinter mainloop (because, afaik, CTk doesn't do matplotlib yet)
Problem:
I create a CTkTopLevel window to display single interactive matplotlib figures (simple line and 3D trisurface). The toplevels close without error, but when destroy() is used to close the mainloop/program a host of errors crops up ONLY WHEN the 3D plot was topleveled/closed.
Errors
bgerror failed to handle background error.
    Original error: invalid command name "2503442563136_checkIfMouseLeft"
    Error in bgerror: can't invoke "tk" command: application has been destroyed
bgerror failed to handle background error.
    Original error: invalid command name "2503735015488check_dpi_scaling"
    Error in bgerror: can't invoke "tk" command: application has been destroyed
bgerror failed to handle background error.
    Original error: invalid command name "2503767702720update"
    Error in bgerror: can't invoke "tk" command: application has been destroyed
bgerror failed to handle background error.
    Original error: invalid command name "2503768283712_click_animation"
    Error in bgerror: can't invoke "tk" command: application has been destroyed

Code that doesn't throw errors:
import customtkinter as ctk
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg,
    NavigationToolbar2Tk
)

self.topframe = ctk.CTkToplevel(self.root)
figure = Figure(figsize=(6, 4))
figure_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, self.topframe )
NavigationToolbar2Tk(figure_canvas, self.topframe )
ax1 = figure.add_subplot()
ax1.plot(x_data, y_data)
figure_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

# if __name__ == "__main__": and root.mainloop and stuff

Code that throws errors:
# same imports
self.topframe = ctk.CTkToplevel(self.root)
figure = Figure(figsize=(8, 8))
figure_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, self.topframe)
NavigationToolbar2Tk(figure_canvas, self.topframe)
ax1 = figure.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
ax1.plot_trisurf(data_x, data_y, data_z)
figure_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

I've tried various attempts at killing/quitting the figures before self.topframe.destroy() and self.root.destroy(), but no luck. I've tried try - except the bgerrors because they don't affect the program, but I haven't been successful.
Is it a problem with mixing CustomTkinter and Tkinter? Is it a problem with closing a 3D interactive plot that doesn't occur when closing a more simple plot?
Thank you

please provide a [mre] and focus on one issue at a time

This usually means that some work has been scheduled with after. I think customtkinter does that a lot, and that code isn't very good at dealing with windows being destroyed.

@Thingamabobs Unfortunately the MRE doesn't recreate the posted bgerrors... so... I have to needle in haystack what the difference is between my 'program' and the MRE.

@BryanOakley I haven't scheduled anything with after, are you saying that ctk may be doing that behind the scenes? How might I try - except my way to ignoring those bgerrors without a blank except clause?

yes, ctk is probably doing that. I think there have been several questions here similar to yours. For example, check_dpi_scaling is a customtkinter function, and the number in front of it implies it was run by after.

something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74488759/tkinter-tclerror-cant-delete-tcl-command-customtkinter-custom-prompt/74489396#74489396
